# multiple variable in for loop list comprehension

Tags: python, for-loop

What is the meaning of the following line of code?

```
arr = [a+b for a,b in list]
```

Generally a 'for' loop is used with a single variable (in this case 'i')

```
arr = [i for i in list]
```

In the first case multiple variables 'a' and 'b' are used inside the for loop, which I am unable to understand. Please explain this format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called unpacking. If the list (or any other iterable) contains two-element iterables, they can be unpacked so the individual elements can be accessed as `a` and `b`.

For example, if `list` was defined as

```
list = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (4, 6)]
```

your final result would be

```
arr = [3, 7, 10]
```

You can unpack as many elements as you need to into as many variables as you need. The only catch is that all the elements of the list must be the same length for this to work (since you are specifying the number of variables to unpack into up front).

A more common usage of this construction (possibly the most common I have seen) is with `enumerate`, which returns a tuple with the index as well as the item from an iterable. Something like:

```
arr = [ind + item for ind, item in enumerate(numbers)]
```

Answer (score 4):

`for a,b in list` deconstructs a list of tuples (or a list of two elements). That is, `list` is expected to be of the form `[(a0, b0), (a1, b1), ...]`.

So, `[a+b  for a,b in list]` results in `[a0+b0, a1+b1, ...]`.

Comment: Any iterable of two elements.

Answer (score 3):

The elements of the `list` are tuples/list with **2 elements** and when we write,

```
 a,b in x
```

we unpack each element to two different variables, `a` and `b`

```
>>> a,b = [1, 2]
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
```

---

**Example**

```
>>> x = [ (i, i*i) for i in range(5) ]
>>> x
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 4), (3, 9), (4, 16)]
>>> [ a+b for a,b in x ]
[0, 2, 6, 12, 20]
```

Comment: Compare it with variable unpacking; `a, b = x`

Comment: @Jollywatt Sorry I didn't get you. `a, b = x` will work as long as `x` has two elements

Comment: Apologies. I was suggesting you mention that this is all an example of variable unpacking, which is the underlying concept. Just so that the OP would realise the relationship between `a, b in x` and `a, b = x`. :)

Answer (score 2):

What's going on is called tuple unpacking.
Each element in `list` should be a tuple or some other equivalent sequence type which can be unpacked.

Example:

```
l = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
arr = [a + b  for a, b in l]
print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[3, 7]    # [(1+2), (3+4)]
```